# Pass data from component to another component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to pass data from a functional component to a class component. This is the code that I try in the functional component.

```
function ViewLocation() {
    const long = posts?.location?.longitude;
    const lat=posts?.location?.latitude;
    const location={lat,long};

    return(
       <Map loc={location}/>
    );
}

export default ViewLocation;
```

This is the code that I try in the class component.

```
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class Map extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        center: {
            lat: 48.639512204153604,
            lng: 1.6496781699692729
        },
        zoom: 11
    };
    render() {
        const {lat, long}=this.props.loc;

        return (
             <div className="location-box-b" style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
                  <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
                    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
                  >
                  <AnyReactComponent
                    lat={lat}
                    lng={long}
                    text="Seller's Location"
                   />
                  </GoogleMapReact>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Map;
```

When I try to set the default center I have to put data to this code part.

```
static defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 48.639512204153604,
    lng: 1.6496781699692729
  },
    zoom: 11
};
```

But when I try to change the values like this

```
static defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: this.props.loc.lat,
    lng: this.props.loc.long
  },
    zoom: 11
};
```

I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'loc' of undefined'. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a Class's instance properties (e.g. `this.props`) within its `static` properties. When you use `this` within a static property, it refers to the Class itself - not an instance. The Class does not have a `props` value (only the instances do), thus `this.props` is undefined. If you're trying to keep track of the center latitude and longitude, you'll need to utilize **[state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)**.

For more information regarding static class properties in ES6: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).